# CI/CD vsts with Azure cloud service

Tags: visual-studio, azure, tfs, msbuild, azure-devops

In VSTS I can build and deploy the Cloud service by CI/CD pipeline. But Build step How can we modify the csdef (cs definition file) according to the custom specification. ?

For ex, By using Visual Studio I can specify the VM size, same How can I achieve in Team services build definition?

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are many extensions that can modify the file, such as [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens), [Release Management Utility tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.utilitytasks), so you can use one of them to update csdef file before build task.

Regarding Replace Tokens extension, it can replace specific token with the value of the variable, for example, there are `#{vmCount}#` token in csdef file and `vmCount` variable in build/release, then that token could be replaced with the value of `vmCount` variable.

There is another sample: [Using Tokenization (Token Replacement) for Builds/Releases in vNext/TFS 2015](https://dustinoprea.com/2016/05/06/using-tokenization-token-replacement-for-buildsreleases-in-tfs-2015/).